# How to choose a method of communication between an app and a server?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, communication

How can I decide what method of communication I should use between a windows phone and a server? I primarily need to send and receive binary data.

What should I take into account when evaluating different methods?  What methods are designed for binary communications, or have issues with this?

Comment: As originally asked, it isn't really acceptable here.  We discourage subjective/poll questions.  As to the question itself, just roll with WCF.  Its the official solution, and therefore has the most tool, documentation and community support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with a web service, but if it's only really simple communication I'd go with simply making POSTs and GETs to the server to remove some of the overhead.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest typically JSON. However for this, I would simply suggest a base64 encoded string, and then convert it back to binary upon success.

Comment: I think he means the method of communication, not how the data is represented